# Trigger to update field based on picklist value that have structured choices

Tags: trigger

I have picklist field contains Zero,First,Second,Third,Four and need to update the Counter field if the user select from First to beyond.Example it will update if user select Zero to First.It Wont update the field if user select First to Zero.Same goes if user select First to Third but not Third to Second or Third to First.

The scenario will be Zero --> First --> Continuously but not backward.I am thinking doing this using Apex Trigger and using List to store value but any logic to implement this easily.

Comment: If you don't have many values, formula field might work.

Comment: Formula field?How it detect that the value must be forward not backward?

Comment: There is a formula function for detecting the previous value of a field.

Comment: Yeah that's true I've forgot that we can't use priorvalue in formulas. Then that trigger is the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do it with apex.

I would create a `Map<String, Integer>` to 'translate' text to integers and then just compare these integers(for example:

```
if (theMap.get(oldValue) < theMap.get(newValue)) {
    // increment your counter
}
```

) to see if the new value is greater than the previous one(and how much bigger if needed)